# Android default music app - add songs from web instead of filesystem

Tags: android, audio, uri, audio-player

I would like to leverage (reuse) the built in Android music app to play songs/artists/albums/playlist that their origin is from the web and not from SDcard/internal storage.

To be more accurate, I see that the content is retrieved from MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

Is there a way to add web audio to the media store?

Basically, why wouldn't it be possible? The mediaPlayer knows how to play remote audio.

Please advise...

Comment: Do you want to do this in Java, or are you asking about using the music app?

Comment: Java-wise - from the developer point of view.